# Can I make the new rosjava project that send the message through existing node?

Tags: turtlebot, message, topic, rosjava, keyboard-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I have a question.

When I enter the command 'roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch', I can see the node '/turtlebot_node, /turtlebot_teleop_keyboard'.

So I think,

If I make the new rosjava project that send the message through '/turtlebot_teleop_keyboard' node, I can actuate the TURTLEBOT using my rosjava project.

Is it possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40711/can-i-make-the-new-rosjava-project-that-send-the-message-through-existing-node?/) by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you may need to start with the general ROS [overview and tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) here.

To answer your question, you would more likely want to communicate directly with the base_controller node. I imagine turtlebot_teleop_keyboard does not have a subscriber that would relay to base_controller. So no, you cannot send a message through it.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-08-07**:
thank you !!